# javascript : filter array of objects using another array as filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

Suppose each employee is a object having

```
emp1.age=30
emp1.name="Hang"
emp2.age=40
emp2.name="Dang"
emp3.age=50
emp3.name="Bang"
```

storing it in Array.

```
var orginialArray=[emp1,emp2,emp3];
```

I want to filter or splice the array with the other array of strings.

Somewhere I'm preparing an array of names to compare with `originalArray` and then remove the unmatching employee from `originalArray`

```
var removeElements=["Hang","Dang"]
```

I tried `filter` but it ends up sending a string in the callback and I could not make it work

```
function filterItems(query) {
  return orginialArray.filter((el) =>
    el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1
  )
}
console.log(filterItems(removeElements)); //i know this is wrong
```

Objective is to filter the original array and only have the employee whose name is not in remove element array.

I also tried splice but also no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) method (which you are already using) and return true only if current employees name does not exist in removeNames array(which you may check by using [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control) ):

```js
var employees = [
  {"name": "abc", "age":"34"},
  {"name": "pqr", "age":"34"},
  {"name": "xyz", "age":"34"},
  {"name": "xxx", "age":"34"},
];

var removeNames = ["xxx"];

// if required, make all removeNames elements lowerCase first
// removeNames = removeNames.map(function(name){
  // return name.toLowerCase();
// });//map()


var filteredEmployees = employees.filter(function(emp){
  return removeNames.indexOf(emp.name.toLowerCase()) === -1;
});//filter

console.log( filteredEmployees );
```

Comment: inside the filter if i want to store the matching name in filtered employees

Comment: @NeverGiveUp161 sorry I did not get that. Do you mean that you want to store the removed employees in a separate array? Also, I think you should create a separate question for a separate problem as it may help other people also.

Comment: its just a minor change,that is the reason.So filteredEmployees now have everything except removeNames content.But i want filteredEmployees 
 should have only matching element in removeNames  array.I think tweaking return removeNames.indexOf(emp.name.toLowerCase()) === -1; would help?

Comment: Sorry I still did not get the exact requirement. You mean you want the logic reversed? That is, now only those elements should be kept which ARE IN removeNames array and others should be filtered out?

Comment: okay :). You just need to change the equality operator to not equal operator i.e. use `return removeNames.indexOf(emp.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1;` instead.

Comment: ok,let me try again.Tried it but did not work,might be i missed something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144850/discussion-between-mohit-bhardwaj-and-nevergiveup161).

Comment: chat is blocked on our network.Already tried continuing.Thanks anyways for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You're close. Since `query` is an array of names, you need to check if the current employee's name is in that array - if so, exclude that employee from the new list, like so:

```js
var emp1 = {
  age: 30,
  name: "Hang"
};
var emp2 = {
  age: 40,
  name: "Dang"
};
var emp3 = {
  age: 50,
  name: "Bang"
};

var originalArray = [emp1, emp2, emp3];
var removeElements = ["hang", "bang"];
function filterItems(query) {
  return originalArray.filter((employee) =>
    query.indexOf(employee.name.toLowerCase()) === -1
  )
}
console.log(filterItems(removeElements));
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer, and I personally didn't downvote it. My guess is you might be getting downvotes due to the fact that it isn't following a functional paradigm.

Comment: @doutriforce There is nothing wrong with the answer and I didn't downvote and I don't disagree with you at all that it could be helpful but as I said, I assume who ever downvoted did not find the answer useful and they don't have to explain why as I'm sure they would have left a comment already if they felt it was worth it to them.

Comment: @zfrisch I agree, my attempt was to keep the code as close to the OP's original code as possible.

Comment: @zfrisch I wasn't the one asking about the downvotes, however. lol someone came by and downvoted every answer and then left - it happens occasionally for no reason. I know my solution is beneficial to the OP, so I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: @mhodges: This filters the unmatched element,any idea on matched? this part === -1

Comment: @NeverGiveUp161 If `=== -1` gives you the unmatched, and "*not* unmatched" gives you matched, then *not* `=== -1` (AKA `!== -1`) will give you the matched. You can also say `> -1` to save a couple keystrokes. Or even fancier, `~query.indexOf(...)` The tilde operator does [a bitwise NOT](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bitwise-not-operator), and only returns false if the value is equal to -1, and returns true for everything else. Which in the case of `indexOf()` is actually perfect (it is just more ambiguous as to what the code is doing)

Answer (score -1):

this is a fully ES6 array method solution. You could do something like this:

```
filterItems(query){
    let newArray = []
    query.map( (qElem) => newArray.push(qElem.toLowerCase()) )
    return originalArray.filter((el) => 
        newArray.includes(el.toLowerCase())
    )
}
```

I'm generating a new array with the query names but lowercase. Then return  a new array with all the elements that do not satisfy the condition of being included in the newArray.
Hope  It helps!

Comment: `map` should not be used for iterating, and in fact, you can use it for its intended purpose (creating a new array with all of the elements of the original array, transformed) easily: `let newArray = query.map((qElem) => qElem.toLowerCase());`.